# Error estimation over multiple instruments readings

Tags: homework-and-exercises, measurements, error-analysis, statistics

A cable factory ships cables in spools of 100 km each. The overall length of each spool is known with great precision, it's 100 km sharp.
In order to speed up the sale process, distance markers are placed on the cables at regular intervals, so when customers need a piece of cable smaller than 100 km, the length is already predetermined.

However, if we would use a second meter counter to check for the accuracy of the factory's we would probably end up with a table like this:

```
Factory mark    Own counter     
 
1.000 km        1.024 km
2.000 km        2.125 km        
3.000 km        2.988 km
4.000 km        4.002 km
5.000 km        5.123 km
6.000 km        5.999 km
(...)           (..)
```

Assuming no prior knowledge about the accuracy of either instrument (the factory's or our own), how is it possible to determine the amount of error, which is presumably not constant, on each single measurement? What kind of information can be inferred by comparing the two readings? How is it possible to minimize the uncertainty on the own counter reading?

Please also note that:

1. the overall length measurement is exact only because it is known *a priori*, not because the factory counter is accurate in the long run.
2. we are NOT conducting multiple measurements over the same physical quantity. A single span of cable is measured by two different instruments only once.

Comment: Does it mean you do not WANT to measure the same piece of cable twice? That could be a way to understand the precision (repeatability) of your instrument.

Comment: Are you aware of the distinction between accuracy and precision? Is this a homework question in statistics, or did you make it up yourself?

Answer (score -1):

> What kind of information can be inferred by comparing the two readings?

You can extract measurement devices precision average difference. Let $$X_i = |a_i - b_i|$$ where $a_i$ is factory device reading and $b_i$ is test device reading. Then average precision difference between devices is $$ \overline {X_i} = \frac {\sum {X_i} } {N} $$

You can also extract standard deviation, which will be $$\sigma = \sqrt {\overline {X_i^{^2} } - {\overline {X_i} }^{^2} } $$

Low standard deviation will indicate that devices are similarly calibrated, i. e. that there is a correlation between devices calibration, despite the fact that average measurement precision difference can be high between them.

Apart from that there is not much you can deduce after. You can not say which device has better accuracy from this data. It's a black box.

Comment: Why the down vote for technically correct answer?